# Setting up Android SDK with Netbeans or Visual Studio?

Tags: android, ide, sdk, installation

I'd like to set up Android SDK with Netbeans or Visual Studio 2010. I am coming back to Windows programming after 3 months on Apple iMac (for iPhone programming).

Would somebody be able to explain how to set up the NetBeans environment so I can compile and test Android Apps directly form NetBeans.

I will be testing on a simulator, not a real device. My platform is Windows 7 Ultimate.

Thanks.

EDIT:

nbandroid is proving annoying to set up. It requires platforms. How do I install those?
It seems I can't use Eclipse even if I wanted to. It can't find the Java VM DLL... Help with that is appreciated.

Comment: if you don't mind me asking.. why do you dev on Windows / use eclipse?

Comment: You should use the recommended Eclipse, not NetBeans

Comment: @Aidan - My laptop is Windows and portable, my iMac, is well, my iMac. Hardly as portable (Although it is easy to transport.) @Pentium10 -  For arguments sake, I like NetBeans  better. The question was not "Which IDE to use". it was, "How do I use NetBeans?"

Comment: Googling 'android netbeans' comes up with quite a few hits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install the Android SDK and a NetBeans plugin called [nbandroid](http://nbandroid.kenai.com/). There are lots of instructions [here](http://wiki.netbeans.org/IntroAndroidDevNetBeans).

I do recommend however using Eclipse because the plugin that you use on that is officially supported by Google, the Netbeans one is community developed I think, and a lot of the tools may be missing (like Allocation Tracker or Emulator controls. I don't know if they are in the netbeans plugin because I haven't used it but I'm guessing you wont have the full range of SDK tools available in the plugin).

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't sound like nbAndroid is your problem.  No matter how you develop you need to select the Android target platforms with the AVD Manager from the Android SDK.

Answer (score 0):

You should download the 'ADT' plugin it allows to kickstart android development directly by using the eclipse exe in the zip file